# Wie sagt man "Ending" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, word-choice

Wie sagt man "Ending" in diesem Zusammenhang?

> Ich schreibe schon seit einer Woche einen Roman, und ich denke über einen Ausgang dafür nach.

Ich kann nicht "Happy end" schreiben, da nicht alle Geschichten in Romanen ein Happy End haben. Ich weiss nicht, ob "Ausgang" hier im Kontext passt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *Ausgang*, but you could also simply use *Ende*.

> Ich schreibe schon seit einer Woche einen Roman und ich denke über ein Ende dafür nach.

Answer (score 1):

In addition or as alternative to *Ende* and *Ausgang* you might want to use:

- *Schluss*
- *Abschluss*
- *Finale* (I'd expect this more for movies, though)

*Ausgang* would more likely be used in the verb form. I.e.:

> Ich schreibe schon seit einer Woche **an einem Roman**, und ich denke darüber nach wie er ausgehen könnte.

Also, the Duden website offers *guter Abschluss* as one of the synonyms for ["Happy End"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Happy_End).

---

Side-note: instead of *schreibe ... einen Roman* I would use the above form *schreibe ... an einem Roman*, but it's probably mostly taste :)

Answer (score -1):

If you´re finishing a novel / short story, then there is only one word:

**Ende**

You cannot use any of the mentioned words by the others. However if you´re telling somebody else about your novel, you can tell them about the finale (where the good guy kills the bad guy in an epic fight), or you could tell a friend you´re about to finish (abschliessen) your novel, or you could tell them what you write at the end (zum Schluss).